# enable_tcp_keepalive in Airflow version 1.10.9

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am using Airflow 1.10.9 via AKS ( Azure ) Kubernetes.

The issue that I am facing is that if the pod status gets terminated completed, the job is still showing as Running on airflow.

The solution I found on the web is to upgrade the Airflow to 2.0 + version, however due to major code changes in the production environment, I am unable to upgrade the Airflow version.

The details about the solution is available at this [Link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14791)
It says that I need to have `enable_tcp_keepalive = True`

Is there a way that I can implement this in Airflow 1.10.9 ? Or are there any other solutions to resolve this ?

Below are the screenshot for references.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Airflow, there is a [`_enable_tcp_keepalive` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.0/airflow/kubernetes/kube_client.py#L70).

You can copy this function definition reference above over to your airflow init script (airflow_local_settings.py).
You should of course clean up the function to your taste.

Then, patch the `get_kube_client` function in your version such that it calls this function.

```py
# file:airflow_local_settings.py

from airflow import kubernetes

def _patch_get_kube_client():
    orig_get_kube_client = kubernetes.get_kube_client
    if kubernetes.get_kube_client.__name__ == 'patch_get_kube_client':
        return
    
    def patch_get_kube_client(*args, **kwargs):
        _enable_tcp_keepalive()
        return orig_get_kube_client(*args, **kwargs)
    
    kubernetes.get_kube_client = patch_get_kube_client

_patch_get_kube_client()
```

Comment: I am unable to find the file airflow_local_settings.py in airflow version 1.10.9.

Comment: That should be in your `${AIRFLOW_HOME}/config/` folder. If it isn't already, create it and copy [`airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4b25cb9d08565502172cb847c79d81559775d504/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py#L10) there.

Comment: I have decided to upgrade the airflow itself. Thanks for the help. By the way can you also help in answering this question as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787378/airflow-clear-dag-api-response-401